# images are not showing in reyclerview, images are coming from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am making an application in which images will be shown in recylerview and all images will be fecthed from firebase. But images are not showing in  reyclerview. I am new to android, can not able to find the issue, please help me.

It is my code:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater, R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    View view = binding.getRoot();
    databaseImage = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("TopApps");
    valueEventListener =databaseImage.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            modelClasses.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot item : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String mImageURL =item.child("imageUrl").getValue().toString();
                String mImageLink = item.child("webUrl").getValue().toString();
                ModelClass modelClass = new ModelClass(mImageURL, mImageLink);
                modelClasses.add(modelClass);
            }
            adapter = new TopRecyclerAdapter(modelClasses, getContext());
            binding.toprecyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

MyAdapter Code:

```
public class TopRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TopRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
ArrayList<ModelClass>modelClasses;
Context context;

public TopRecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<ModelClass> modelClasses, Context context) {
    this.modelClasses = modelClasses;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public TopRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.topapps_layout, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TopRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Picasso.get().load(modelClasses.get(position).getImageUrl()).into(holder.imageView);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return modelClasses.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CircleImageView imageView;
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.circleimg);
    }
}
```

}

ModelClass:

```
public class ModelClass {
String imageUrl;
String imageLink;

public ModelClass(String imageUrl, String imageLink) {
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    this.imageLink = imageLink;
}

public String getImageUrl() {
    return imageUrl;
}

public String getImageLink() {
    return imageLink;
}
```

}

Database Structure:

[image]

Please tell me what is the issue. Why images are not showing in recyclerview.

Comment: is your database rules set to true and have you defined internet permission in manifest?

Comment: i just checked the rules, these were false now i set them to true, now it is woking fine.Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

// These rules will allow anyone read or write access to your database

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```